# How to render 2 json's in JSX

Tags: json, reactjs, jsx

I have 2 json's which I get on making 2 different API calls.

```
fetch(`veb/api/roleDetails/${id}`).then(response =>
         response.json()
     ).then(responseJson => {
         console.log('responseJson = ' + JSON.stringify(responseJson));

         this.setState(() => {
             return {

                 allRoleDetails: responseJson,

             }
         });
     }
         ).catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
```

2nd:

```
fetch(`/api/api/itemTypes`).then(response =>
    response.json()
).then(responseJson => {
    console.log('responseJson = ' + JSON.stringify(responseJson));
    this.setState(() => {
        return {

            names: responseJson,
          }
    });
}
    ).catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
```

in the 1st api call I get itemtypeid from which I have to make the 2nd api call to fetch the name of the typeid.Even if I get a combined json it will be fine
How to do that?Any help will be great.
Thanks

Comment: You might need to put the 2nd fetch inside the 1st fetch and use the allRoleDetails json to loop through the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Promise.all` is what you need. Basically, what it does is merging a collection of promises into one single promise, and return the resolved values one everything inside the collection done.

```
Promise.all([
  fetch(`veb/api/roleDetails/${id}`).then(response => response.json()),
  fetch(`/api/api/itemTypes`).then(response => response.json())
]).then(([allRoleDetails, names]) => {
  // allRoleDetails is the resolve of your first promise
  // names is the resolve of your second promise
}).catch(err => {
  // catch error here
});
```

More details about `Promise.all` can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all